# How to use plotcandle() function only if the statement is true?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

candleplot = input(defval=false , title='Plot Candle')

plotcandle(0,var7, 0, var7, color=var7>xrf(var7,1)?#FFF700:#3FFF00 ,editable=false)

i am writing like this

if candleplot

```
plotcandle(0,var7, 0, var7, color=var7>xrf(var7,1)?#FFF700:#3FFF00 ,editable=false)
```

But its giving error cannot use plotcandle in local scope.

I want to plot the candel when someone tick the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a [ternary conditional](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) on the value of **close**

```
plotcandle(0,var7, 0, candleplot ? var7 : na, color=var7>xrf(var7,1)?#FFF700:#3FFF00 ,editable=false)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect , worked cheers ! 
You saved me...

i asked this to very famous pine script indicator developer lonesometheblue, and he said u can't use any plot function with condition,,,

now i got my answer thanks man...

my discord if u want to join : discord.gg/pUyTaM2HkG